# Is there a simpler method to get slice of a tensors as shown in the following example?

Tags: python, tensorflow, slice

I want to do slicing of tensors like the following slicing in numpy. How can I do that?

```
# numpy array
a = np.reshape(np.arange(60), (3,2,2,5))
idx = np.array([0, 1, 0])
N = np.shape(a)[0]
mask = a[np.arange(N),:,:,idx]


# I have tried several solutions, but only the following success.
# tensors
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np


a = tf.cast(tf.constant(np.reshape(np.arange(60), (3,2,2,5))), tf.int32)
idx2 = tf.constant([0, 1, 0])

fn = lambda i: a[i][:,:,idx2[i]]
idx = tf.range(tf.shape(a)[0])
masks = tf.map_fn(fn, idx)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(a))
    print(sess.run(tf.shape(masks)))
    print(sess.run(masks))
```

Is there a simpler method to achieve this ?

Can I use function `tf.gather` or `tf.gather_nd` to achieve this ?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**1.Another method**

I'm not sure if it's the best way, but it's faster. You can use `tf.boolean_mask` instead of `tf.map_fn`.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

a = tf.cast(tf.constant(np.reshape(np.arange(60), (3,2,2,5))), tf.int32)
idx2 = tf.constant([0, 1, 0])

fn = lambda i: a[i,:,:][:,:,idx2[i]]
idx = tf.range(tf.shape(a)[0])
masks = tf.map_fn(fn, idx)

# new method
idx = tf.one_hot(idx2,depth=a.shape[-1])
masks2 = tf.boolean_mask(tf.transpose(a,[0,3,1,2]), idx)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print('tf.map_fn version:\n',sess.run(masks))
    print('tf.boolean_mask version:\n',sess.run(masks2))

# print
tf.map_fn version:
 [[[ 0  5]
  [10 15]]

 [[21 26]
  [31 36]]

 [[40 45]
  [50 55]]]
tf.boolean_mask version:
 [[[ 0  5]
  [10 15]]

 [[21 26]
  [31 36]]

 [[40 45]
  [50 55]]]
```

**2.Performance comparison**

The vectorization method 1000 iterations takes `0.07s` and the `tf.map_fn`method 1000 iterations takes `0.85s` on my 8GB GPU memory. The vectorization method will be significantly faster than the `tf.map_fn()`.

```
import datetime
...
with tf.Session() as sess:
    start = datetime.datetime.now()
    for _ in range(1000):
        sess.run(masks)
    end = datetime.datetime.now()
    print('tf.map_fn version cost time(seconds) : %.2f' % ((end - start).total_seconds()))

    start = datetime.datetime.now()
    for _ in range(1000):
        sess.run(masks2)
    end = datetime.datetime.now()
    print('tf.boolean_mask version cost time(seconds) : %.2f' % ((end - start).total_seconds()))

# print
tf.map_fn version cost time(seconds) : 0.85
tf.boolean_mask version cost time(seconds) : 0.07
```

I believe that the performance difference will become more obvious as the shape of `a` increases.

Answer (score 0):

## Another method use `tf.gather_nd`:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np


a = tf.cast(tf.constant(np.reshape(np.arange(60), (3,2,2,5))), tf.int32)
idx = tf.range(tf.shape(a)[0])
idx2 = tf.constant([0,1,0])
indices = tf.stack([idx, idx2], axis=1)
a = tf.transpose(a, [0,3,1,2])
masks = tf.gather_nd(a, indices)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(a))
    print(sess.run(tf.shape(masks)))
    print(sess.run(masks))
```